# Audio from RTCPeerConnection is not audible after processing in AudioContext

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, web-audio-api

I have active `RTCPeerConnection`. I want to process this audio. I'm creating `new AudioContext()` and then new nodes: `MediaStreamAudioSourceNode` to `MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode`

After connect `MediaStreamAudioSourceNode` to `MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode` I can't hear audio.

`MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode` is connected to `Audio` element.

- I've tried connect directly `MediaStream` from `RTCPeerConnection` to `Audio` and it works
- I've also tried connect `MediaStreamAudioSourceNode.mediaStream` to `Audio` element and it also works.
- I've connected `MediaStream` returned by `getUserMedia()` and it works even with `MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode`

It looks that only `MediaStream` from `RTCPeerConnection` does not work with `MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode`.

```js
  function play(eventWebRtcPeerConnection) {
    const audio = new Audio()
    const ctx = new AudioContext();

    let mediaStream = new MediaStream();
    eventWebRtcPeerConnection.streams[0].getAudioTracks().forEach(track => mediaStream.addTrack(track));

    // create source and destination and connect them
    const msSource = ctx.createMediaStreamSource(mediaStream);
    const msDestination = ctx.createMediaStreamDestination();
    msSource.connect(msDestination);

    // play media stream on Audio object
    audio.srcObject = msDestination.stream; // does not work
    // audio.srcObject = msSource.mediaStream; // works

    audio.oncanplay = async () => {
      audio.muted = false;
      await audio.play();
    }

  }
```

I expect to hear audio after connect `MediaStreamAudioSourceNode` to `MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode`.

Comment: That's a known issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=933677

Answer (score 4):

The somewhat confusing answer is that at least Chrome requires you to connect the MediaStream coming from a WebRTC connection to an Audio element directly. I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature. The good news is that you can mute this Audio element. Your code would then look like this:

```
const mutedAudio = new Audio();
const outputAudio = new Audio();
const context = new AudioContext();
const mediaStream = new MediaStream();

peerConnection.streams[0].getAudioTracks().forEach(track => mediaStream.addTrack(track));

mutedAudio.muted = true;
mutedAudio.srcObject = mediaStream;
mutedAudio.play();

const source = context.createMediaStreamSource(mediaStream);
const destination = context.createMediaStreamDestination();

source.connect(destination);

outputAudio.muted = false;
outputAudio.srcObject = msDestination.stream;
outputAudio.play();
```

You can also skip the `outputAudio` element and connect the `source` directly to the `destination` of the `context`.

Comment: Do you have a link to something explaining the rationale behind this limitation? Your answer saved me from wondering why this wasn't working. Is this the best workaround available for this issue?

Comment: This issue does at least indirectly reference the problem: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=687574 I don't know of any other workaround.

Comment: Wow. Thanks @chrisguttandin. You just saved my entire night!

Comment: for me its even no need to play "fake" audio
just need to create `new MediaStream()`, assign it as a `srcObject` and add any track into it